# Model collection inside a Model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am a complete newbie in asp.net mvc. And i'm stuck with some problem and don't yet know how to solve it. I googled, found some useful things, but they haven't helped me with solving my problem. So let's begin with what i have now:

```
public partial class Dish
    {
        public Dish()
        {
            PortionFood = new HashSet<PortionFood>();
        }    
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [JsonIgnore]    
        public virtual DishCategory DishCategory { get; set; }
        [JsonIgnore]
        public virtual ICollection<PortionFood> PortionFood { get; set; }
    }
}
// Food class in a separate file
public partial class Food
    {
        public Food()
        {
            PortionFood = new HashSet<PortionFood>();
        }
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public float Proteins { get; set; }
        public float Fat { get; set; }
        public float Carbs { get; set; }
        public float Ccal { get; set; }
        public float? Sugar { get; set; }
        public float? AmountOfWater { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("FoodCategory")]
        public int IdFoodCategory { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("FoodConsistencyType")]
        public int IdFoodConsistencyType { get; set; }
        [JsonIgnore]
        public virtual FoodCategory FoodCategory { get; set; }
        [JsonIgnore]
        public virtual ICollection<PortionFood> PortionFood { get; set; }
    }
}
// Portion Food Class in a separate file 
public partial class PortionFood
    {
        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 0)]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        [ForeignKey("Food")]
        public int IdFood { get; set; }
        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 1)]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        [ForeignKey("Dish")]
        public int IdDish { get; set; }

        public float Amount { get; set; }

        public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }

        public virtual Dish Dish { get; set; }

        public virtual Food Food { get; set; }
    }
}
```

PortionFood just specifies what amount of what Food is inside which Dish.
Now i have views for classes Dish and Food, and i am able to add new object of each of these two classes(by filling in the view fields and pressing the button) to DB, i am able to edit an existing Dish && an existing Food. See list of all existing Food && Dish objects. 

**What i want:**
When adding/editing a Dish there must be a possibility to add a PortionFood object releated to current Dish(which we are editing or adding). Just by selecting a FoodId in a dropdown list, setting an amount and clicking the button. The PortionFood object must be inserted to PotionFood collection of related Dish and related Food
How can i implement it?
 
If there're any uncretainties write in a comment, and i'll try to make it clear.

Thank's for help!

Comment: Answer somewhat depends on how you want the user experience to be. I am thinking an AJAX request would do well here. If you choose not to use AJAX you will have to submit the whole form; which is easier to code but the whole page will refresh everytime you want to submit your PortionFood.

Comment: @FailedUnitTest , for now i'd prefer what's easier, because i don't have too much time

Comment: In that case generate the dropdown, when user selects and submits the whole thing, populate ICollection with the dropdown entry (you won't be able to bind the dropdown value directly to ICollection so bind it to a single value). You will have to store ICollection somewhere, so that everytime a user submits you can add to it.

Comment: @FailedUnitTest i don't understand how can i populate dropdown list with ICollection entry?.. In my dropdown i choose the food, and in a field somewhere near a dropdown i set an amount, then i push a button, when a button is pushed in my DishController an action starts it's work. This action must accept an PortionFood Element from a view as it's argument..as far as i know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I see your problem now, you need to populate from ICollection not to it. In that case I suggest using `List<SelectListItem>` because you can then use DropDownListFor html helper.
For example:

```
public class ViewModel {
    private readonly List<PortionFood> _foods;

    [Display(Name = "Pick a portion")]
    public int SelectedFoodItem { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> FoodPortionItems
    {
        get { return new SelectList(_foods, "Id", "Name"); }
    }
}

public class PortionFood {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

//In your Razor View:
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.SelectedFoodItem)
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedFoodItem, Model.FoodPortionItems)
```

That should help you populate the dropdown.

PS: I usually like to use ViewModels instead of Models here, that way you only have what you need in the View